# Canvas arcTo method draws inconsistent arcs in Chrome

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to use the arcTo method to draw several arcs of different colours along the circumference of a large circle.

See my codepen [here](http://codepen.io/looeee/pen/xZPRwq?editors=001)

```
$(document).ready(() => {
   let canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
   let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

   //draw a point on the canvas, optional radius and colour
   const drawPoint = (point, radius, colour) => {
      let col = colour || 'black';
      let r = radius || 2;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.fillStyle = col;
      ctx.fill();
   }

   //draw an arc on the canvas using arcTo, optional colour
   const drawArc = (p1, p2, p3, r,colour) => {
     let col = colour || 'black';
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
     ctx.arcTo(p3.x, p3.y, p2.x, p2.y, r);
     ctx.strokeStyle = col;
     ctx.stroke();
   }

  ctx.translate(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/3);

  //circle radius and path have been calculated by another function
  let c = {x: 1052.5390625, y: 506.8760978034711};
  let radius = 1096.702150363923;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(c.x,c.y,radius, 0, Math.PI*2)
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();

 //now I want to draw several arcs of different lengths and colours on this circle

 //Heres the first arc 
 //(again points on the circle are calculatedby a different function,     I've entered them manually here)
 let p1 = {x: 288.88884710654133, y: -280.26680862609};
 let p2 = {x: -39.00216443306411 , y: 400.6058925796476};
 let p3 = {x: 0, y: 0};
 drawPoint(p1, 4, 'green');
 drawPoint(p2, 4, 'green');
 drawPoint(p3, 4, 'green');

 drawArc(p1, p2, p3, radius, 'green');

 let q1 = {x: 49.879184148698684, y: 62.546518597442386}
 let q2 = {x: 80, y: 0}
 let q3 = {x: 63.94929512052109, y: 30.796357420674724}

 drawPoint(q1, 4, 'red');
 drawPoint(q2, 4, 'red');
 drawPoint(q3, 4, 'red');

 drawArc(q1, q2, q3, radius, 'red');

});
```

There is a large black circle, then a large green arc with three green control points, and a smaller red arc with red control points.

In Firefox it works fine, the arcs all line up Chrome (well, Chromium) at large screen sizes they do not.

Chromium Version 47.0.2526.106 Ubuntu 15.10 (64-bit)

Comment: Yep, it looks like the arcTo command behaves slightly differently in Chrome vs FF/Edge. Can't say if Chrome or FF/Edge are inaccurate since we don't have more of your code. You might have to workaround by using `arc` commands instead of `arcTo` commands.

Comment: Yes, I currently have it working using the arc command, unfortunately the code is a lot more complicated due to the complexity of calculating starting offsets. 

The rest of the code is not really relevant here, as the points were calculated using some basic trigonometry. They are correct, which means that its Chrome which is inaccurate.